# Cosmos DB metrics report 100x more requests than expected

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm comparing the service side metrics of my app with the metrics emitted by Cosmos DB and I can see a 100x difference in request counts.

Is my container misconfigured? Am I querying the wrong way? Is Cosmos performing multiple requests internally for each query I'm running against it?

The metric I'm looking at in Cosmos is TotalRequests/Count/5min.
The container has indexes on all attributes + a few composite indexes.
The query I'm running is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE x.partitionKey = 0
and x.index1 = 1
and x.index2 = 2
```

The container is suffering from a VERY hot partition.
Each request consumes about 5 RUs.
The consistency level is BOUNDED_STALENESS.

I tried changing the consistency level to EVENTUAL which brought the consumed RUs down, but I'm still seeing a huge amount of requests that aren't accounted for.

Comment: It's unclear what your specific issue is. You mention "100x difference in request counts" - what does that mean? Also, regarding hot partitions: there's really no way to know what's going on since we don't know how you partitioned your data (e.g. what value distribution you have in your `partitionKey` property). And no, Cosmos DB does not run multiple queries for each of your queries, unless you're doing cross-partition queries (or following a continuation token to fetch more data)

Answer (score 0):

The Total Requests metric includes every request between the SDK and the service. The SDK makes frequent calls to the service when an SDK instance is first created, then makes regular calls for metadata and other information. If you want to see just requests made by user, apply a filter for OperationType and select the operations you want to monitor.

It's not clear why you were using Bounded Staleness. Reads using Strong and Bounded Staleness consume twice the RU/s because they read from 2 replicas rather than 1 replica for the other weaker consistency models. In addition to differences in cost, there are of course differences in whether you may read stale data or not. They also play a big role in your RTO and RPO in multi-region scenarios.

A hot partition does not have impact on throughput consumption. 5 RU/s for a query is actually very good.